# How to modify XML as text in lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XML file generated by an IDE; however, it unfortunately outputs code with newlines as BRs and seems to randomly decide where to place newlines. Example:

```
if test = true
    foo;
    bar;
endif
```

becomes the following XTML within an XML file:

```
<body>
    <p>if test = true<br />    foo;<br />    bar;<br />endif
    </p>
</body>
```

I am trying to make a pre-processor for these files in python using lxml to make it easier to version control them. However, I cannot figure out to modify the XML as text so that I can place each BR on it's own line like the following:

```
<body>
<p>if test = true
    <br />    foo;
    <br />    bar;
    <br />endif
</p>
</body>
```

How does one edit the xml as text, or failing that, is there another way to get the results like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to add a new-line character to the `p` tag's text and `br` tag tails. Example:

```
from lxml import html

data = """
<html>
<body>
<p>if test = true<br />    foo;<br />    bar;<br />endif
</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(data)

p = tree.find('.//p')
p.text += '\n'

for element in tree.xpath('.//br'):
    element.tail += '\n'

print html.tostring(tree)
```

Prints:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>if test = true
<br>    foo;
<br>    bar;
<br>endif

</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I did need to add some testing to make sure that I hadn't already added a \n at the end in case I had  run the script on the same file twice, but other than that this was  exactly what I was looking for.